# Isekai light novel where the protagonist removes the slave collar from his teacher's elf wife

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember part of a light novel I read before where a bit after the beginning, he removes a slave collar (or some form of collar) off of his teacher's wife, who happens to be an elf. Can't remember the name for the life of me, so please help!

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Isekai novel but have manga tag. So this is novel adapted to manga or adapted from manga?